# How to check response status for http error codes using Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I want to check the response status and export it to CSV file using Scrapy. I tried with `response.status` but it only shows '200' and exports to the CSV file. How to get other status codes like "404", "502" etc.

```
def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'URL': response.url,
            'Status': response.status
        }
```

Comment: Yes I know that but is there any options to get them printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings you can adjust these to make sure certain error codes are not automatically filtered by scrapy.

##### HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES

Default: []

Pass all responses with non-200 status codes contained in this list.

##### HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL

Default: False

Pass all responses, regardless of its status code.

`settings.py`

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL = True

HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [500, 501, 404 ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `errback` to the request and then catch the http error in the `errback` function and yield the required information. Get more information about the errback function in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing). See sample below

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://example.com/error", errback=self.parse_error)

    def parse_error(self, failure):
        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            yield {
                'URL': response.url,
                'Status': response.status
            }

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'URL': response.url,
            'Status': response.status
        }
```